# Centering images within container

Tags: css

I am creating a site that has multiple pages that each have different images on them - of varying sizes. I have used the below css to center the whole page:

```
.container {
width: 960px;
margin: auto;
}
```

I am not sure how to then center these images on each page. I am currently using left margin and doing it by eye but this doesnt seem right especially since each image needs a different margin. Am is missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

e.g HTML

```
<div id="image_description_multipleimages">

<section id="image_container_multipleimages">

<img src="main_content_images/1.HOSS.png" id="hossimage1">
<img src="main_content_images/2.HOSS.png" id="hossimage2"> 
<img src="main_content_images/3.HOSS.jpeg" id="hossimage3">                 
</section>

<section id="description">

<h2> Hoss Intropia</h2>
</section>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#hossimage1 {
width:600px;
height:399px;
margin-left:50px;}

#hossimage2, {
width:600px;
height:908px;
margin-left:136px;}

#hossimage3 {
width:600px;
height:1025px;
margin-left:50px;}

#image_description_multipleimages {
clear:both;
width: 600px;
height: 2500px;
margin-left:130px;
margin-top:60px;
}

#image_container_multipleimages img{
margin-top:15px;
float: left;
clear:both;}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `text-align: center;` on their container div. This will align them to the center like it would text.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zH383/)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
#hossimage1 {
width:600px;
height:399px;
margin-left:50px;
position:relative;
top:t px;
left:y px;
align:center; 
}
```

in each hossimage1, hossimage2, hossimage3 id.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this pattern

```
<div class="parent">
    <img class="child">
    ...
```

With the following CSS

```
.parent {
  display: flex; /* Here is the trick */
  height: someContainerHeight;
  width: someContainerWidth;
}

.child {
  width: someElementHeight;
  height: someElementWidth; 
  margin: auto;  /* Here is the trick */
}
```

You will get the image perfectly centered automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set `img` to `display:block;`, and make `margin-left` and `margin-right` both `auto`:

```
img { display:block; margin:0 auto; }
```

See example using your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Lh3U/